# Mysql throwing Out of Memory when changing innodb_tmpdir variable to larger partition

Tags: mysql, indexing, bigdata, innodb

I want to index a very large column in a very large table. The default `/tmp` does not have enough disk space and is throwing [no space left on device error](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/02/25/mysql-error-1034-incorrect-key-file-on-innodb-table/).

I have a much larger partition where I can point `innodb_tmpdir` to.

- I created a a tmp dir in this partition: `/mnt/partition/tmp`
- Changed the permissions of this directory to 777 `chmod -R 777 /mnt/partition/tmp`
- Then I set the innodb_tmpdir variable to point to this directory via mysql client: `SET VARIABLE innodb_tmpdir='/mnt/partition/tmp';`
- The variable is set correctly by executing: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_tmpdir';`

The issue arises when I try to create an index with the following basic command structure:

```
create index a on b (c, d, e, f);
```

The following error is instantly thrown:

```
ERROR 1041 (HY000): Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space
```

What is with this error? o I need to set some permissions/configs for my partition?

**NOTE 1** I am running all this via a terminal console not some third party client (i.e. in foreground not in background)

**NOTE 2** If I do not set `innodb_tmpdir` and keep everything to default, the index command runs without this issue. (obviously it crashes halfway through due to the limited disk space which is the actual reason why I am changing tmpdir

**my.cnf**

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
wait_timeout=604800
interactive_timeout=604800
local_infile=ON
binlog_expire_logs_seconds=600
skip-log-bin
```

**swap size:** 8.39GB

**MYSQL Version:** 8

Machine is fully dedicated to mysql

Comment: what's the version of MySQL? 32 or 64 bit? can you add full content of your my.cnf? how much memory/swap does the machine have? is there anything besides mysql that's memory-hungry?

Comment: @pQd added the details in question. Could it simply be because I am running client in foreground from terminal rather than background? (it seems to be working from a third party client creating the index in background)

Comment: running in background - i doubt. can you add info about: total available memory [ just include output of command 'free' ], exact version of mysql [ just include the banner shown by the mysql command line ], information if it's 32 or 64 bit build [ run "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version_compile_machine';" from mysql command line ]. are /etc/mysql/conf.d/, /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ empty? if not - please include content of all the files kept there. thx!

Comment: Was that SET done in the same connection as the ALTER?

Comment: @RickJames - thank you for your comment about buffer pools total size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. The reason was that Ubuntu's `Apparmour` was blocking mysql from accessing other file systems. You need to change apparmour's configs to allow read and write on partition

[This](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/apparmor-and-mysql-v2) is the detailed solution that solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

in your config you're giving MySQL 4GB of memory for buffer pools. is that covered with available physical memory? do you actually have > 6GB or more RAM available? if not - please start with decreasing size of innodb buffer pool so the total amount is few GB below available physical memory.